# textblock* on every page

Tags: page-breaking, longtable, text-manipulation, everypage

I have following:

```
\begin{textblock*}{15mm}(191mm,20mm)
    \begin{spacing}{6.2}\noindent\thin\color{black}
         {\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont 
         M\\
         Y\\
         T\\
         E\\
         X\\
         T}
    \end{spacing}
 \end{textblock*}
```

And I have a longtable:

```
\begin{longtable}[ht]{p{.37\textwidth} p{.518\textwidth}}
....
\end{longtable}
```

This longtable will go over two - three pages and I want my textblock displayed on every page, where this longtable will be continued. Currently it is only displayed on first page. (Code above is in a separated file "file.tex")

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings, mdframed}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\include{content/file}

\end{document}
```

In the file.tex is only the textblock* and longtable. Nothing else.

**EDIT:**

As a workaround I have solved this by defining it in header. So I use

```
\fancyhead[LO]{\text}
\include{content/file}
\fancyhead[LO]{}
```

where `\text` is my `\newcommand` which is the textblock. But a proper solution to include in file.tex and simply repeat it as hook(?) on every continued page would be great.

Comment: I think, you should provide more information. Do you have a `\endfirsthead` statement after this textblock stuff?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Yes, but even now, it does not compile. It complains about `spacing`

Comment: I don't have any problems to compile it

Comment: Well, you've got the whole stuff on your disk ;-)

Comment: Try to use `eso-pic` package with `\input`.

Comment: @Harish Kumar: could you provide an example?

Comment: @x4k3p Difficult without a working MWE. I will try later when I get some time.